# LDAP authentication and get all user data in C# / MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I've LDAP credentials, those are

- LDAP Host: ldap.abcd.net
- LDAP Port: 636
- Use SSL
- Base DN: dc=testbd,dc=net
- User: uid=hris,ou=People,dc=testbd,dc=net
- Password: abc123

using this I can connect and get all users by using a software named "Softerra LDAP Administrator", but while using C#/ .net MVC 
I've used this code which gives "Unknown error (0x80005000)" while search.FindAll();. I have also tried without Port number.

```
 DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAPS://ldap.abcd.net:636/", "uid=hris,ou=People,dc=testbd,dc=net", "abc123");

         DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection) { Filter = ("(objectClass=*)") };
         search.CacheResults = true;
         SearchResultCollection allResults = search.FindAll(); //Getting "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
```

I've tried another way it also gives "Unknown error (0x80005000)"

```
DirectoryEntry nRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAPS://ldap.abcd.net:636/ou=People,dc=testbd,dc=net");
        nRoot.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
        nRoot.Username = "uid=hris,ou=Group,dc=testbd,dc=net";  //full dn

        nRoot.Password = "abc123";

        DirectorySearcher nDS = new DirectorySearcher(nRoot);
        nDS.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        nDS.Filter = "objectClass=*";

        SearchResult sr = nDS.FindOne();// Getting ""Unknown error (0x80005000)"
```

I've tried many other ways but not getting proper data that software "Softerra LDAP Administrator" getting. Please help me through that I can all user information from LDAP and validate one user data. Thank you.

Comment: You are using AuthenticationTypes.None which sounds ok for simple bind authentication with DirectoryEntry. the DN of the username in the second example is not the same as the one in the first example is it normal ?

Comment: Your LDAP connection appears to be written LDAPS instead of LDAP. Maybe that's where the issue resides.

Answer (score 0):

THE SOLUTION

```
             var ldapDomainName= "LDAP://ldap.xserver.net";
             var loginId = "testUser";
             var password = "aa1111";
                       // assign user
                        var uid = "uid=" + loginId.Trim() + ",ou=People,dc=servicenginebd,dc=net";
                        // assign password
                        var passwordLdap = password;
                        // define LDAP connection
                        var root = new DirectoryEntry(
                            ldapDomainName, uid, passwordLdap,
                            AuthenticationTypes.None);

                        try
                        {
                            var connected = root.NativeObject;
                             return "LDAP Login SUCCESSFUL";
                            //isValid = true;
                            // no exception, login successful
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            // exception thrown, login failed
                            return "LDAP Login FAILED";
                        }
```

Comment: Could you also give some explanation?